# Linearization to estimate uncertainty

Tags: linearization

Consider a cone of height H and diameter D

Use linearization to estimate the allowable percentage error in the measurement of D if the colume of the cone is to be determined to within 2% of its true value?

So I know you are supposed to differentiate the volume of a cone, but by what and why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a right circular cone, the volume is given by$$V=\frac \pi {12}D^2H$$ Use logarithmic differentiation to get
$$\frac{dV}V=2\frac{dD}D+\frac{dH}H$$ Going from the $d$'s to $\Delta$
$$\frac{\Delta V}V=2\frac{\Delta D}D+\frac{\Delta H}H\implies \frac{\Delta D}D= ???$$

Comment: Hi, but how will I know the value of $\frac{\Delta H}H$ ?

Comment: May be, no error on $H$.

Comment: So the answer is 4%?